# Is there a practical limit of clients that a UDP server can simultaneously handle?

Tags: sockets, udp

My game requires a lobby where players will gather before being assigned a dedicated/separate server where they will actually play the game. This lobby is rather trivial and the only operations there are Login, Ping, StartGame. The server needs to keep only basic information about a client, is he logged in or not, but not much other resources.

I have done some tests with a simple TCP server, and I can support a maximum of about 10000 connections before the overhead gets me. So, to support 100000 players I will need to deploy a server farm, at least 10 machines, and on top add synchronization between the servers...

I was looking into possibility of doing the same using UDP. I am not worried about connectionless or unreliable nature of UDP, I understand this, and there is plenty of UDP vs TCP articles. My question is practical/architectural in nature. In the above scenario, what is the practical limit, how many packets per second can a single UDP server handle? Is it realistic to expect that a UDP server can handle 100000 packets per second? Which machine? Anything that Amazon EC2 can offer.

Any insight or further reading will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Comments suggest I can get unlimited (100000+) TCP connections... I must be missing something, but, can anyone make the code below get to 100000 connections.

```
public class Server
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Listening...");
        try
        {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(22222);

            ArrayList<Socket> sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();

            while (true)
            {
                sockets.add(ss.accept());
                if (sockets.size() % 100 == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println(String.format("Received %d connections.", sockets.size()));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Client
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Socket> sockets = new ArrayList<Socket>();

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                sockets.add(new Socket("localhost", 22222));
            }
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *a maximum of about 10000 connections before the overhead gets me* You should be able to handle more without special tricks. Which method are you using ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Java, NIO, single thread selector. But even if I remove all overheads, I will hit TCP port limit, and I will not be able to handle more then 65K simultaneous connections. Am I missing something?

Comment: TCP port limit ? What do you mean ? Think about the way a stack demultiplexes a connection (the 5-tuple). I.e. there's no limit since different clients can use the same source port.

Comment: After TCP connection is accepted, it is actually assigned a port where all subsequent communication is performed. It is all transparent to your app. These ports are called http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port . You can also search for "TCP Port Exhaustion" as this is closely related.

Comment: @MikiJ: Ephemeral ports are only used when binding a socket locally when calling `listen()` or `connect()`. A client connection that is accepted by a listening socket inherits the same local port as the listening socket that accepted it.  The only limit to the number of client connections that can be accepted by a server is available system resources, not port exhaustion.  Port exhaustion happens on the client side, not the server side.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, No no, MikiJ is right. The number of ports open simultaneously is limiting your ability to have over some 64K connections (the first 1024 ports being reserved). If you connect/disconnect then you can reuse the ports. If you stay connected "forever" as in a game, then the port is "lost" for the duration of the game.

Comment: @AlexisWilke: read my comment again more carefully. On the **CLIENT SIDE**, port exhaustion is a possibility as a client uses a random ephemeral port unless `bind()` is explicitly called before `connect()` is called. On the **SERVER SIDE**, there is no possibility of port exhaustion as all connected clients are assigned to same port that the server is listening on. A server can have more than 64K clients connected to it as long as it has enough resources available (memory, thread stacks, etc).

Comment: @AlexisWilke: And FYI, the OS does NOT reserve ports 1-1024, otherwise HTTP servers, FTP servers, etc would not work!